# Xbee S2B firmware upgrade over wired or Over The Air without XCTU

Tags: xbee, firmware, ota, xmodem

I am using Xbee S2B ZB modules for a project.

But am not able to follow Digi Xbee User manual instructions to update the firmware Over The Air or via wired medium without using XCTU software. It's on page 21 here http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000976_V.pdf.

If anyone has done this, I would appreciate the help to follow me up stepwise how to achieve that over wired as well as OTA. Also what is Xmodem and how does it work?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C, there's an [Open Source XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library/) with support for [wired firmware updates](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library/blob/master/src/xbee/xbee_firmware.c) and a [sample program](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library/blob/master/samples/win32/install_ebl.c) to do the updates.  It also includes an implementation of [XMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM), a simple, well-known protocol for sending files over a serial connection.

You may be able to adapt that code to work over-the-air as well, but that update process is going to be more complex.